# SQL to change values (var char(20)) of a column

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

Table_neme:**employee details**

```
--------------------------------------------
c_bp_id | value | name  |address
--------------------------------------------
10001   |001    |john   |
10002   |mathew |mathew |
10003   |002    |Ann    |
10004   |003    |isabel |
10005   |maria  |maria  |
10006   |Adam   |Adam   |
```

i want to change change column 'value' in to

```
--------------------------------------------
c_bp_id | value | name  |address
--------------------------------------------
10001   |001    |john   |
10002   |**005**|mathew |
10003   |002    |Ann    |
10004   |003    |isabel |
10005   |**006**|maria  |
10006   |**007**|Adam   |
```

kindly help me please ?

Comment: have you tried looking into UPDATE ?

Comment: See this http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-update.html and try yourself

Comment: Are the asterisks there because they are a required part of the data, or to highlight that those are data changes?

Answer (score 1):

well it could be something like this:

```
with cte as (
    -- create row_numbers for all values where value is text
    select
        c_bp_id,
        row_number() over(order by c_bp_id) as rn
    from Table1
    where value !~ E'^\\d+$'
)
-- updated
update Table1 as t set
    value = lpad((rn + 1 + (select coalesce(max(value::int), 0) from Table1 where value ~ E'^\\d+$'))::text, 3, '0')
from cte as c
where c.c_bp_id = t.c_bp_id;
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/71bf0/9)</kbd>**

It's a wierd query and I don't recommend to put this one into production, but you can use it if it's one time update. I also don't know why did you skip `004` value and start to numerate from `005`.